# How to divide BN by a decimal

Tags: solidity, web3js, gas

I am trying to divide BN with a constant and I can't find the right function.
Basically I wanted to divide 132876 by 1.30, `132876/1.30` for BN operations.
Here is a snippet of what I tried.

```
const gasAmount = new BN(132876) 
console.log(gasAmount.div(new BN('1.30')).toString()) // 160
console.log(gasAmount.div(new BN(1.30)).toString())   // 132876

// expected: 102212
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web3.js lib is already supporting BigNumber so you don't have to add the library twice. Try this:

```
const gasAmount = web3.utils.toBN(132876);
console.log(gasAmount.divn(1.30).toString());
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It gives the exact same result that this user is complaining about. You've only changed `div(new BN(1.30))` to `divn(1.30)`, which are essentially identical. And the reason why it doesn't work, is that class BN simply does not support decimals.

Comment: BTW, what does "you don't have to add the library twice" mean? There is no evidence of something like that in the question.

Comment: @goodvibration ```new BN``` is by default not supported in browsers, so I guess he added that library, but he don't need it, because he have web3.js already.

Comment: And ofcourse I've tried it, the question is have you tried it :) result - https://ibb.co/1vS5zv9

Comment: Yes, I have tested **the exact code in the question**, using web3.js v1.2.11 and NodeJS (i.e., not a browser). The results are exactly as stated in the question. This version of web3.js, uses class `BN` rather than class `BigNumber` as you wrote in your answer. I suspect that your browser imports web3.js v0.x, and that you have changed `BN` to `BigNumber` when you tested it.

Comment: That's my web3 version - 1.0.0-beta.36

Comment: There's a good chance that this version uses `BigNumber` (which supports decimals) rather than `BN` (which doesn't support decimals). Assuming that this dude is using a more recent version of web3.js, your code won't fix his/her issue.

Comment: But to be honest, I'm not sure how `web3.utils.toBN` actually works in this version of web3.js, unless it has already switched from `BigNumber` to `BN`. Are you sure you didn't use `web3.toBigNumber`?

Comment: https://streamable.com/uama5u Does this make things clear? ```web3.utils.toBN``` method is part of any web3 version above ```1.x.x```. Read more here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#tobn

Comment: Ah yes, `divn` works, I wasn't aware of that!!! Although my answer (below) technically works, and although the quote about class `BN` not supporting decimals is taken directly from the official documentation, your answer renders mine wrong in the sense that class `BN` actually **does** support decimals (well, at least as as input). Kudos and +1!

Comment: I would get rid of the opening statement though ("add the library twice") because it doesn't really seem to be the case in the question.

Comment: P.S.: I'd still recommend to avoid using decimals anywhere in the code (other than for printing, displaying user data, etc). In other words, use `muln(130).divn(100)` rather than `divn(1.30)`.

Comment: Thanks, both worked i might follow @goodvibration suggestion to not use decimal

Comment: @Marr: Undeleted the answer, so others can follow.

Answer (score 2):

Class `BN` does not support decimals, [as stated in the official documentation](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/#usage):

> Note: decimals are not supported in this library.

So change this:

```
gasAmount.div(new BN(1.30))
```

To this:

```
gasAmount.mul(new BN(130)).div(new BN(100))
```

Or even to this:

```
gasAmount.muln(130).divn(100)
```

Comment: Undeleted the answer, because it appears that class `BN` actually **does** support decimals in a certain way (at least as input). The other answer is correct, and even provides a more simple solution (as I've also mentioned in the comments to it). I still recommend to avoid using decimals anywhere in the code (other than for printing, displaying user data, etc), so I'm keeping this answer here as an optional solution.